# Can a VPN protect from malware when on public WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, vpn, malware

I used public WiFi once, and ended up having to factory reset my phone due to a virus/malware. Since then, I've simply avoided public WiFi. I'm going to be signing up for a VPN service, now that the internet privacy rules have been repealed. I'm just wondering if the use of a VPN will protect me from public WiFi viruses/malware, or if it will only protect me from prying eyes?

Comment: No;  Using a VPN will not protect you from malware.  Since I don't believe in submitting answers, that contain a single statement, I will allow somebody else to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Ramhound stated, a VPN won't protect you from downloading / installing malware or viruses. Only your data will be encrypted, securing you from man-in-the-middle-attacks or from sniffing login-data, for example.

I wonder how being connected to a public WiFi infected your phone with a virus or malware. Without downloading some suspicious app or whatever, simply connecting to a public WiFi won't be a serious risk if you keep your software up to date and don't expose any important information.

Keep in mind, using a VPN secures your connection and data, not your phone / tablet / any device.

Comment: Not sure how it happened either. I didn't download or install anything while connected to the WiFi.

Comment: @Tester101 - Your browser downloaded about 15 different files without your knowlege just loading this page.  All of them were images of course.  Most malware is downloaded without direct user consent, but indirectly downloaded through ( hidden iframes,ect)

Comment: @Ramhound so there's no hope avoiding it?

Comment: Sure there is;  you block known hosts that distribute malware, it's not perfect, but bad performers don't often change.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a GOOD VPN will protect from a number of types of attack which will certainly reduce your exposure to malware.

Note, however, recent reviews of at least Android VPN's which found that many of them did absolutely nothing at all!!

There are a number of issues beyond basic effectiveness that you also need to take into account.

Firstly whether the VPN client directs DNS queries via the VPN, some don't which massively reduces your privacy though it wouldn't impact attack protection that much.

Secondly, whether the VPN handles "captive portal" pages. These are the pages you have to connect to on initial connection to the Wi-Fi that usually make you log in. It is at this point you are most vulnerable to attack. Because a VPN is designed to tunnel all of your traffic past the local network, obviously you cannot access the captive portal page when the VPN is fully formed.